# Trying to understand anti TCP SYN flood attack IPTables rule

Tags: iptables, tcp, denial-of-service

I’m currenlty working on a university assignment. I’m learning about firewalls and I need to configure IPTables on a Ubuntu machine to prevent a [TCP SYN flood attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYN_flood).

I understand that this type of attack consists in sending a server a great number of SYN requests without then following with an ACK after its SYN-ACK response, resulting in the server waiting and therefore wasting its resources.

Looking of the Internet I found this IPTables rule on multiple web sites:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m state --state NEW -j DROP
```

I cannot understand how this entry should prevent the attack. I’m interpreting it as “Drop any new TCP connection without a SYN flag.” Am I missing something?

Comment: perhaps you could try to use the "unclean match" or "limit match" switch.   e.g. iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --syn -m limit --limit 1/s -j ACCEPT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That iptables rule will not prevent SYN flood attacks. As you say, it will drop any new, non-SYN TCP packets. It will only accept new TCP connections which include a SYN packet.

To prevent SYN flood attacks using iptables, you would need to employ rate limiting.

Comment: Thank you for your help. What the articles I had read were referring to is still a mistery but at least I could find a IPTables rule based on rate limiting to include in my assignment!

Answer (score -3):

Synflood is a so outdated technique like winnuke. Linux kernel includes its own protection (net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies) since [1999](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt?v=2.2.26)(!), so your only job is to enable it with sysctl - but this is default for a long time.

```
sysctl net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=1
```

Comment: This is the recommended method since 1999, so using iptables is pointless. If it was a _well known_ rule, then he has already found it via searching internet.

Comment: SYN flood is outdated? Huh. So it's not used as a key part of the [Mirai](http://www.itworldcanada.com/article/reports-offer-more-detail-on-mirai-iot-botnet-locky-ransomware/388547) [botnet](http://thehackernews.com/2016/10/mirai-botnet-iot-malware.html) which was responsible for a 620 Gbps attack on [Krebs website](https://krebsonsecurity.com/2016/09/krebsonsecurity-hit-with-record-ddos/) or the 1.2 Tbit/s attack on [Dyn](http://www.networkworld.com/article/3134057/security/how-the-dyn-ddos-attack-unfolded.html)? Yeah, sounds pretty trivial like winnuke to me.

Comment: I understand you are passionate about the topic but I have to turn in the assignment today and still have no clue why that IPTables rule should prevent the attack.